# Rebasing with -X option

Tags: magit

This is my scenario:

- My branch is rebased against some other branch
- that other branch changed and I want to get mine back to sync
- I do a rebase and magit makes me go through all commits and merge

In terminal I would do this with a `git rebase -X ours root-branch`. Is something like that possible with magit? If that's not possible, is there some alternative for what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That wasn't available yet, but I've just added it with [46b2f6e3a](https://github.com/magit/magit/commit/46b2f6e3ad74c879debe54af5bd3aee81d460f74).

Because this should only be used if you know what you are doing, it is hidden by default. To learn how to reveal it, see [Enabling and Disabling Suffixes](https://magit.vc/manual/transient/Enabling-and-Disabling-Suffixes.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to give an upvote.

Comment: You are welcome! You should accept the answer by clicking on tick mark thingy.

Comment: Thanks for that advice also, I didn't know that is clickable!